# Take Flask Form Data Input and Turn it Into Pandas Dataframe For ML Modeling

Tags: python, pandas, flask

I'm building a small flask application to take in form data from an HTML. I'd like to convert this form data (each selection get put into a column) into a Pandas DataFrame. I will then use a pickle file to create a prediction off this DataFrame. Problem i'm having now is not knowing how to convert the data I have inputted into a Pandas DataFrame.

I believe I have my request information in my variable result but i'm not sure how to proceed from here.

## App.py File

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def student():
    colours = ['RED', 'BLUE', 'BLACK', 'ORANGE']
    return render_template('student.html', colours = colours)

@app.route('/result',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
    def result():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        result = request.form
        return render_template("result.html", result = result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=8080) #run app in debug mode on port 5000
```

## student.html

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="http://localhost:8080/result" method="POST">
        <p>Year of Test <input type="text" name="TestYear" /></p>
        <p>Yeah of Student <input type="text" name="StudentYear" /></p>
        <p>State of Student <input type="text" name="StudentState" /></p>
        <p>Origin State <input type="text" name="OriginState" /></p>
        <p>Shirt Color <select name=color method="GET" action="/">
            {% for colour in colours %}
            <option value="{{colour}}" SELECTED>{{colour}}</option>"
            {% endfor %}
        </select></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="submit" /></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass your data like this:

```
@app.route('/result/<name>',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def result(name):
   # you can use your variable name in here given from the html form.
```

is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: I actually think my data is coming in properly through the student.html file but I don't know how to retrieve the data that is imported and turn it into a Pandas Dataframe. My apologies for not making this more clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Convert **HTML form input** to **Dictionary** and then to **Pandas dataframe**

```
@app.route('/predict/<target>',methods=['GET','POST'])
def predict(target):
    d = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('POST received')
        d = request.form.to_dict()
    else:
        print('GET received')
        d = request.args.to_dict()
    print(d)
    print(d.keys())
    print(d.values())

    print("Dataframe format required for Machine Learning prediction")
    df = pd.DataFrame([d.values()], columns=d.keys())
    print(df)

    return 'Predicting %s' %target
```

On browser, paste the GET url - http://localhost:8080/predict/TTT?a=1&b=2&c=3

or

Execute with POST command:

```
curl -d "a=1&b=2&c=3" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST http://localhost:8080/predict/TTT
```

Output:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Aug/2020 04:46:25] "GET /predict/TTT?a=1&b=2&c=3 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
GET received
{'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3'}
dict_keys(['a', 'b', 'c'])
dict_values(['1', '2', '3'])
Dataframe format required for Machine Learning prediction
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
```